# On Bing, find search terms NOT on a given domain

Tags: search, bing

On [Bing](http://www.bing.com) I know I can add

```
site:<somedomain>
```

to include only results from that domain, but is it possible to exclude results from that domain? The obvious

```
-site:<somedomain>
```

does not appear to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... OK it does appear to work like this, not sure what I did wrong previously! Doh!